# iOS 17.0 Core Image after changing Exposure and Brightness CIFilter, image has black pixels

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, ciimage

I have a photo editor feature in my app and after iOS 17.0 update, I started to have black pixels all over image after applying exposure and brightness. Same code works fine below iOS 17 so I assume it's something related to latest changes.

```
if filterName == "CIExposureAdjust" {
        if let filter = CIFilter(name: filterName) {
            filter.setDefaults()
            filter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            filter.setValue(value, forKey: kCIInputEVKey)
            return filter.outputImage!
        }
        return image
    }
```

Has anyone had the same issue?